# How to make editable PDF with Crystal Report?

Tags: pdf, visual-studio-2015, crystal-reports

I have a `Crystal Report` template using `Visual Studio 2015` and `Crystal Report 11`.

I am trying to make an editable PDF when I export it. Some fields with data that could be modified when the PDF is exported. Other data will not be able to be changed.

Is it possible to do that, I mean, export an editable PDF using Crystal Report?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can not export pdf with editable fields, crystal report does not support.

check this links -

https://archive.sap.com/discussions/message/13967957

https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3340683

Better to ask in SAP forum that they have any support.

For this you need third party tool - https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28076120/Editable-PDF-from-Crystal-report.html